# Xml elements present in spite of null values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, for-xml-path

I have a fairly big `SELECT ... FOR XML PATH`. As you know, by default xml elements corresponding to fields with a null value don't appear in the result xml tree. It appears to be a real problem for me and I want to always have ALL the elements appear, whether the value is null or not.

Is there a way to achieve that without surrounding each field by `ISNULL(...,'')` one by one (more than 50 fields in my SELECT !) and without changing the `FOR XML PATH` into `FOR XML ELEMENTS` to use the `XSINIL` switch (which is unfortunately available only with `ELEMENTS`) ?

I suspect these 2 not-entirely-statisfying solutions would result in different outputs, by the way : `<fieldname></fieldname>` and `<fieldname/>` respectively. If possible I'd prefer the first one, but I am anyway eager to read your precious suggestions.

Thanks in advance ! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> without changing the FOR XML PATH into
>   FOR XML ELEMENTS to use the XSINIL
>   switch

You can use `elements xsinil` with `for xml path`.

```
declare @T table (ID int identity, Name varchar(50))

insert into @T values ('Name1')
insert into @T values (null)
insert into @T values ('Name2')

select
  ID,
  Name
from @T
for xml path('item'), root('root'), elements xsinil
```

Result:

```
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <item>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <Name>Name1</Name>
  </item>
  <item>
    <ID>2</ID>
    <Name xsi:nil="true" />
  </item>
  <item>
    <ID>3</ID>
    <Name>Name2</Name>
  </item>
</root>
```

Comment: Just discovered that by myself and it solved my problem perfectly ! I can even keep attribute-mapped fields in my `SELECT` (yet in this case I must explicitly use `ISNULL` to have them appear if they are null). My question expressed clearly a misknowledge and confusion between things. Thanks a lot Mikael. It's the second time you rushed to my aid on a sql problem and I'm deeply recognizing to you (and about to raise a statue of you as my SQL guru ! ;-))

Comment: @Ssithra A statue would be much appreciated :). I am glad to be able to help.